# Вызов атрибута data

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Не могу разобраться, как вызвать атрибут data, есть шаблон на bootstrap, есть Notifications, вызывается он с помощью кнопки

```
<button data-notify-type="info" data-notify-icon="fa" data-notify-message="Congrats! You've reached level 12!">Info</button>
```

Как вызвать Notifications например при открытии страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/#methods) сказано, что нужно для начала сохранить нотификацию в переменную.
После этого, нотификацию можно вызывать вручную.

```
var notify = $.notify('...');
notify.update('title', '...');
```